# How to bind javascript to ctools modal load

Tags: 7, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I have a ctools modal popup that has no Drupal generated form but an external iframe that loads a form into ctools modal. I have some jQuery codes to be invoked when the iframe gets reloaded (ie. to assume external form gets submitted).

This jquery code initiated and works fine with a normal page(without ctools) while javascript has been added by `drupal_add_js()`.

How can I do the same with cTools?

```
// MENU
function dw_common_menu() {
  $items['download/%ctools_js/register'] = array(
    'title' => 'Register',
    'page callback' => 'dw_common_ajax_download_register_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
// Page callback
function dw_common_ajax_download_register_page($js = NULL) {
  /*
   * $sess_key : create a unique session key if not exists;
   * @TODO : instead of md5(REQUEST_TIME) use some other random function as multiple users
   * might access at a same time.
   */
  $output = "";  
  $iframe_source = 'http://example.com/cn/iframe.form.php';
  $output .= '<iframe id="site-contact-us" src="' . $iframe_source . '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="232" height="378"></iframe>';
  // Attaching jquery iframe event load in the ctools output itself. 
  // The script from files are not invoking as window.load() doesn't takes effect in ctools window.
  $jsscript = "";
  $jsscript = 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    (function is_key_authorized(){
      alert(\'sd\');
    }
      });  
    })();
    is_key_authorized();
    });';
  $output .= '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">' . $jsscript . '</script>';
  // Fall back if $js is not set.
  if (!$js) {
    return $output;
  }
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');
  return ctools_modal_render('Register', $output);
  exit;
}
```

Here I am trying to concatenate `<script>` to ctools modal output as `drupal_add_js` not helping to load.

Comment: drupal_add_js? You should be able to write whatever JS in the drupal_add_js function, including raw written stuff... check out this [link on drupal SE](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9318/drupal-add-js-and-inline-code), also - you need to make sure whatever Javascript you're loading via AJAX is binded in after it's called, you should check out the .ajaxComplete() jQuery function, or the .bind() function.

Comment: That did add js but for some reason didn't invoke when ctools modal got loaded; something that adding inline code did. But I couldn't get what I am trying to do.

Comment: You hava a .ready() function on your document... you should try it with .ajaxComplete or something that binds the javascript you're loading, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715351/how-to-execute-jquery-function-after-ajax-page-load)

Comment: Jeet, do you find any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe this answer can help someone - I know I searched for an answer for a while.

I had a similar issue, I wanted to execute some javascript when a specific page of mine was rendered by ctools modal.

I found the answer in the help folder of the ctools module ctools/help/modal.html :

> If you need to do more than just render your modal, you can use a CTools $commands array. See the function ctools_modal_render() for more information on what you need to do here.

How to apply that to this situation: you need to grab the contents of the very small `ctools_modal_render()` function and use it to add commands to the array of commands that is executed in the function. This is the function:

```
function ctools_modal_render($title, $output) {
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_display($title, $output);
    print ajax_render($commands);
}
```

This is what my snippet looks like in my page - I wanted to add a body class among other things, so I could style the `#modalBackdrop` for the modal overlay based on context, so here's my modified page function:

```
function gc_alterations_modal_page($js=null){

    $page = array();

    $page['search-results'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<p>My Markup</p>'
    );

    if( $js ) {
        // Required includes for ctools to work:
        ctools_include('modal');
        ctools_include('ajax');

        // alternate to using: ctools_modal_render('Search', $page);
        $commands = array();
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('body', 'addClass', array('myclass-modal'));
        $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_display('Search', $page);
        print ajax_render($commands);
        return;
    }

    return $page;
}
```